# OSError: [WinError 123] Syntax error in file name, folder name, or volume label

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, kivy

I am a beginner Python user. I ran into a problem when installing the "Kivy" package, even any package, I get an error "OSError: [WinError 123] Syntax error in file name, folder name, or volume label".

Here my error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AHProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "D:\AHProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "D:\AHProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 553, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "D:\AHProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 563, in _handle_target_dir
    ensure_dir(target_dir)
  File "D:\AHProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 105, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "D:\Python3.10\lib\os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Python3.10\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 123] Syntax error in file name, folder name, or volume label: 'D:\\AHProject\\~\\D:'
```

I have already shoveled the entire Internet but did not find a solution to the problem on my question. I'm working with PyCharm, but even when I try install package in cmd I have the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How are you installing the package? [Having a tilde in the file/name](https://superuser.com/q/1666765) isn't necessarily a problem, but a path that has the drive letter `D:` twice seems very strange.

Comment: @bad_coder Thank you for your feedback, I tried to install it while: PyCharm console, interpreter settings and cmd. And everytime I had same error: Syntax error, I tried to reinstall PyCharm and Python, but nothing has not changed

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the installation steps, it's necessary to know exactly what steps you took so the problem can be reproduced exactly. Did you create a fresh venv and [use this dialogue](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#interpreter-settings) having the right venv chosen for the project? If using the terminal did you activate the right venv? How did you run pip in both cases?

Comment: @bad_coder Yes, I always create a fresh venv, which I use for current project. If I use cmd I go to activate venv in my project by using command "activate" and use command "pip install kivy" and then I have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing Anaconda and for me everything works now